# Is memcpy unsafe?

Tags: memcpy

#### Duplicate:

> [Memcpy() in secure programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870019/memcpy-in-secure-programming)

---

According to "[Please Join me in welcoming memcpy() to the SDL Rogues Gallery](http://blogs.msdn.com/sdl/archive/2009/05/14/please-join-me-in-welcoming-memcpy-to-the-sdl-rogues-gallery.aspx)" `memcpy` is being banned as unsafe.  It makes sense that `gets()`, `strcpy` and similar apis  where the destination size is unclear.  Is `memmove()` next?

Comment: What exactly is the question?  The linked to article describes why memcpy was banned in the SDL, security issues tied to it, and suggested replacement.

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870019/memcpy-in-secure-programming

Comment: If they want safety, why the heck are they still using C?

Answer (score 7):

The point with all these “safe” methods is:

> Of course, you can easily make a call to `memcpy_s()` insecure by getting the buffer sizes wrong.

[[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/sdl/archive/2009/05/14/please-join-me-in-welcoming-memcpy-to-the-sdl-rogues-gallery.aspx)]

Which is why I find this SDL feature highly over-hyped. Of course, such problems are inherent in a language like C if no precautions are taken *by the compiler* (or an appropriate runtime, which would be costly in terms of performance and/or memory).

It also makes programs less portable which I personally find is a huge disadvantage. Of course, Microsoft wouldn't necessarily agree.

Migrating the code to C++ with proper use of (checked) iterators might make more sense, where possible. These operations, while *also* inherently unsafe, are more easily used right, and make wrong code stand out. Of course, caveat emptor, and all those C fans and C++ deniers will be after my skin now …

Answer (score 0):

memmcopy might create an opening  for stack overflow by a malicious user. For example: The specific flaw exists during the processing of a malicious WordDocument file.
The overflow can be triggered during the parsing at offset 0xb4c in the WordDocument
stream. At this offset, there is a WORD size that is used as the third parameter
to a memmove call.

Comment: So essentially then you'd use the secure version to check your input for you. The root problem - assuming no one will ever try to screw with you by carefully corrupting your files - still remains.