# Best practice for memcpy in C

Tags: c, memcpy, tr24731

1. Is it same deprecated in GNU as in Microsoft C runtime?
2. Is deprecation, if there is such in GNU C, enforced by later standard of C after 89/90 or the compiler?
3. If it's GNU C compiler, since when and does it provide such a secure alternative memory operating function like `memcpy_s` to the deprecated `memcpy` in Microsoft C?
4. If it's later C standard after 89/90, since when and does it provide such a secure alternative memory operating function like `memcpy_s` to the deprecated `memcpy` in Microsoft C?
5. If no such deprecation in GNU C runtime, is there a function which is neither among those memory operations (name started with `mem`) nor the one I know as `bcopy`, but I can use to copy memory safe in that it takes a parameter about length of the destination?
6. If there is/are, could you please list as many as possible?

Comment: Let me assure you that the deprecation of good old `memcpy` is a mere Microsoft invention, trying to impose a kind of so-called "safety" that doesn't really fit the domain. There is no problem in using `memcpy` and if Microsoft some day dares to completely drop it (which won't ever happen), they'll loose any customers they might still have.

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870019/memcpy-in-secure-programming

Comment: @Qnan I have viewed that before posting these questions. That's why I wrote `...nor the one I know as bcopy,...` in question 5.

Comment: @ChristianRau I think I'm liberal in the first 4 questions. I would appreciate the answer more to question 5 and 6.

Comment: @Yang that was basically the answer to the parts 5 and 6 of your question -- you don't need `memcpy_s` or its variations to write safe code.

Comment: If you want bound checking, why not implement a wrapper over the array yourself and use that?

Comment: @Qnan I was about to do until the last moment before posting questions. I was in the hope that such snippet exists in either glibc or what I might have missed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memcpy_s` has been in added since C11 but is an optional extension. `memcpy` has not been deprecated in C and is not an obsolescent function.

`glibc` as of now does not support `_s` functions and there is no plan (AFAIK) for `glibc` team to support them.

Comment: ...and about question 5 and 6, any idea?

Comment: `memcpy` *has always* taken an argument specifying the length of the destination. MS is simply on crack with regards to this one.

Answer (score 6):

**The function `memcpy` is not deprecated**. It's one of the safest and most useful functions in the library. The `memcpy_s` function became standard in C11 (optional, see "*Bounds-checking interface*" in Annex K).

Comment: ...and about question 5 and 6, any idea?